# Watch folder on server for new images to compress

Tags: javascript, node.js, watch, imagemin

I have a server and it gets a lot of image uploads. The app uploading the images is based in PHP. However, I want to use Node to watch the upload folder, then run imagemin on any new images.

I was thinking I would use npm packages 'watch' and 'imagemin'. I am not sure how to configure them exactly though or how to have it run all the time.

So far I have the following which I can turn on manually:

```
var Imagemin = require('imagemin');
var watch = require('watch');
var imagemin = new Imagemin()
  .use(Imagemin.pngquant());
watch.createMonitor('images', function (monitor) {
  monitor.files['images/*.png']
  monitor.on("created", function (file) {
    compressImage(file);
  })
  monitor.on("changed", function (file) {
    compressImage(file);
  });
});

function compressImage(file) {
  var dest, path;
  path = f.split('/');
  path.pop();
  dest = path.join('/');
  imagemin.src(file).dest(dest).run();
}
```

After a couple of files are added though I get a warning about a `possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit` and then it stops working.

Is there a better way to do this and how can I run it automatically?

Answer (score 2):

To deal with the recursive firing of the watch function on change, one possible solution is this:
Whenever your compression function runs, have it store the filename in a var. On your change listener function, just add

```
If (file !== lastFile) {
   //do something
}
```

There is another module that is quite similar you could try, called [chokidar](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar).

Has very similar hooks as watch:

```
watcher.on('add', function(path) { log('File', path, 'has been added'); })
watcher.on('change', function(path) { log('File', path, 'has been changed'); })
```

Examples here: [Watch Files and Directories](http://davidwalsh.name/node-watch-file)

Comment: I think the issue is that when it overwrites the image, it sees that it changed and tries to compress it again. I am not sure how I can accomplish this without moving the file to another location.

Comment: You could also potentially add a second layer of validation that checks last filename and a time stamp.  That way if the same file gets uploaded again it will get compressed again, as long as it wasn't in the last 10 seconds or whatever.

Comment: I modified the uploads to old files are deleted instead of overwritten which means I just need the on add event. I believe I have the script working now, just need to get it to run when the server starts.